# Minergate CLI mines only XMC but not Monero XMR

Tags: monerod, cpu-mining, cli

I downloaded the minergate CLI and I use the command for starting it:

```
./minergate-cli --user myemail@email.com --xmr
```

I also tried

```
./minergate-cli -user myemail@email.com -xmr
```

And did this on 2 different laptops, no matter which currency I put in the command, from the GUI and the website I can see that the active miners are only on monero classic, xmc and no other. I want to mine monero (XMR) using the cli, am I doing something wrong? With the GUI works perfectly, but I think that the terminal would be faster. Not sure what I am doing wrong, I followed their tutorial and downloaded the latest version.

`MinerGate-cli-4.04-Mac` Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little research, you'll find that Minergate is widely regarded by the Monero mining community as a scam. Use a real miner and pool.

Miners:
[xmrig](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig), [xmr-stak](https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak)

Pools:
http://moneropools.com/

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. I am newbie and I am doing it mostly for learning, I am uninstall it immediately :D

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your mining.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Minergate, it's a scam.
Try XMrig https://xmrig.com/ or xmr-stak https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak/.
They are both good, if you still need assistance post here.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. I am newbie and I am doing it mostly for learning, I am uninstall it immediately :D